# How to move by defun without moving up a level?

Tags: python, javascript, navigation

I am attempting to navigate methods in a file. Typically these are javascript or python files, which have a classes at the "top level", which in turn have methods nested within those definitions.

When I try to navigate by defun (`end-of-defun` or `beginning-of-defun`) the cursor will often end up at the next or previous class definition, not the next or previous method.

Is this the intended behaviour? How can I navigate by the methods?

Comment: Not an answer, but see the doc of variable `beginning-of-defun-function` and command `beginning-of-defun`.